# Фильтрация/сортировка POST массива

Tags: массивы, post, php

День добрый, подскажите как правильно сортировать массив данных к примеру POST, у меня при sumbite массив содержит 20 чисел которые мне нужно занести в базу данных к нему еще естественно приплетается submit и еще 5 параметров которые вносить в базу данных мн не надо. То есть массив содержит 26 элементов а занести в базу мн нужно только первые 20. Придумал такой вариант задавать имена нужных мне полей

> name=cell-0-1, name=cell-0-2 и т.д.
>
> Потом цикле foreach через explode(), и array_shift
> определяю равен ли первый ключ массива == cell

Если да то заношу в новый массив $final если нет пропускаю.
По завершении в базу заношу массив $final

Может посоветуете как еще проще можно все не нужное вкидывать из массива?!

Comment: @Cone, а не проще ли передавать два массива: один, который нужно закидывать в БД и второй, который при sql-запросе игнорируется? Откуда вы эти данные берете? Из формы?

Comment: Да из формы, данные которые не надо заносить используются для условий  при занесении в базу данных.

Comment: > Да из формы

Вот и замечтательно. Для полей формы, которые заносятся в базу, добавляйте в атрибут name, что-то в этом роде:

    <input type="text" name="to_db[num_1][]">
    <input type="text" name="to_db[num_2][]">
    <input type="text" name="to_db[val_100500][]">

Для остальных полей можно ничего не задавать или тоже поместить их в массив:

    <input type="text" name="ignore[other_val_1][]">
    <input type="text" name="ignore[other_val_2][]">
    <input type="text" name="ignore[other_val_100500][]">

Comment: Спасибо Deonis, теперь обрабатывать формы стало на много легче.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте в форме имена полей с скобками [] чтобы показать, что это массив

```
<form action="sample.php" method="POST">
    <!-- массив с нарастающим индексом -->
    <input type="text" name="cell-0[]" value="one" />
    <input type="text" name="cell-0[]" value="two" />
    <input type="text" name="cell-0[]" value="three" />
    <input type="text" name="cell-0[]" value="four" />

    <!-- массив с заданным индексом -->
    <input type="text" name="cell-1[1]" value="five" />
    <input type="text" name="cell-1[2]" value="six" />
    <input type="text" name="cell-1[aaa]" value="seven" />
    <input type="text" name="cell-1[bbb]" value="eight" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

```
<?php
// файл sample.php
foreach($_POST['cell-0'] as $index => $value)
    echo 'cell-0[', $index, '] = ', $value, "\n";

foreach($_POST['cell-1'] as $index => $value)
    echo 'cell-1[', $index, '] = ', $value, "\n";
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо! Возьму на заметку